# Promises en ionic

Tags: promesas, ionic3

Estoy practicando en ionic para aclarar conceptos. En este caso las promesas.

Tengo una app con 2 paginas login y home.

quiero que en el login valide un usuario, si existe me redireccione al home. En caso contrario se quede en el formulario de la misma pagina.

Esta validación la estoy haciendo en el método ionViewWillEnter de la pagina login, donde busco datos del usuario en SQLite.

El problema es que la validación no se realiza, el resto del código se sigue ejecutando antes de que el promise termine. Espero darme a entender.

Cuando inicio la app, esto no funciona. Pero si introduzco datos en el login y voy a home, y luego regreso al login esto si funciona.

Creo que el problema es la llamada asincronica del promise, pero como controlarla para que termina y recién ahí se siga ejecutando lo demás.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Código ejemplo de como lo estoy planteando:

```
public mensaje: string;

ionViewWillEnter(){

    this.dbServiceProvider.getUser().then(
        (data) => {
            this.mensaje = "Ejecuto";
        },
        (err) =>{
            this.mensaje = "Error";
        }
    ).catch(
        (ex) => {
            this.mensaje = "Excepcion";
    });
}
```

Código de pruebas, cuando inicia la app (en la pantalla login), el texto no se muestra... luego de login ingreso a Home, retrocedo nuevamente a la pantalla de login y entonces si se visualiza el texto. ¿Por qué?.

Comment: Buenas @Alejandro, un poco de código para que nos hagamos a la idea de como lo estas montando vendria genial ;)

Comment: `promise.then(()=> { /* Tú código */ })`

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. Actualice aunque no es mucho. donde pongo validación puedo poner también un texto para que se muestre en la vista cuando se carga pero tampoco funciona. Sin embargo cuando voy a Home y regreso a login, entonces si funciona todo correcto. Es eso lo que no entiendo. Gracias nuevamente por comentar.

Comment: Ayudaría si enseñaras el resto de código (el que se ejecuta según dices sin que termine la promesa) y dónde lo llamas.

Comment: Hola, no es de mucha importancia el resto de código (ademas de que se haría todo mas engorroso), puse un código de prueba que no funciona como quiero. Ese es el principal problema.

Comment: agregar que el metodo getUser retorna una consulta básica de SQLite (SELECT * FROM users).

Comment: No estoy seguro pero creo que lo que ocurre es que usando el hook `ionViewWillEnter` el DOM no está aún cargado. Prueba a ejecutar tu código en `ionViewDidEnter` y comenta si arregla el problema.

Comment: Si. Lo mismo pensé, también lo probé (recién lo volví a intentar por las dudas), pero tampoco funciona. No entiendo por qué.

Comment: Es extraño, no se me ocurre nada, la verdad. Si haces un `console.log` te muestra algo aunque no actualice la vista?

Comment: agregue mi dbServiceProvider. Haciendo pruebas, le asigne un valor directamente a la variable mensaje (furea del dbServiceProvider.getUser......) en el metodo ionViewWillEnter() y si se muestra. Pero por qué dentro del promise no?

Comment: Vale, creo que he encontrado algo. Me explico, Todos los eventos del ciclo de vida de ionic están relacionados con un Nav Controller. Al cargar un componente `root`, no hay ningún Nav-Controller, así que los eventos no se disparan. Al volver atrás, y volver al login, estás usando el Nav-Controller por eso te funciona. Aquí recomiendan o usar los ciclos de vida de Angular `ngOnInit`. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10154

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisar y comento.

Comment: Toda la razón. Funciona perfecto. Desde ahora lo tendré presente a la hora de desarrollar con ionic. Muchas gracias. Ponla como respuesta para puntuar :D

Comment: De nada! Lo tendré en cuenta yo también, ya que hace que no toco ionic y seguramente también me hubiera pasado! Así que gracias a tí también!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traduzco literalmente de un reporte de GitHub, el cual tiene el mismo problema:

> This is to be expected. Since all these event are related to the
>   nav-controller, there needs to be a parent nav-controller. Since
>   you're loading a root component, there is no parent nav-controller, so
>   no events fire.
>
> If you need to catch event when that root component is rendered, you
>   can use the angular lifecycle hooks. Or, if you need to subscribe to
>   when child components are loaded, there are observables you can use.
>   http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/components/app/App/

**TRADUCCIÓN**

> Este comportamiento es el esperado. Puesto que todos estos eventos
>   están relacionados con el nav-controller, se necesita que haya un
>   nav-controller padre. Puesto que estás cargando un componente root, no
>   existe un nav-controller padre, así que ningún evento se dispara.
>
> Si necesitas capturar eventos cuando ese componente root se renderiza,
>   puedes usar los ciclos de vida de Angular (ngOnInit en este caso). O
>   si necesitas subscribirte a cuando un componente hijo es cargado, hay
>   obserbables que puedes usar.
>   http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/components/app/App/